# How to Access Nested Data in Object Maps / Collections

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a collection that gets automatically returned in my app when I call a function, and it turns out something like this:

```
Collection {
    '1234567890' => Message {
        channel: TextChannel {
            type: 'text',
            id: '362557066864230402'
        },
        type: "DEFAULT",
        content: "test"
    }
}
```

I'm unsure about the **'1234567890' => Message** part. I understand that it's ES6, but I don't know how to call any of the nested data inside of it, such as **content: "test"**.

To get to that (assuming the collection is using the variable **collection**, I've tried:

```
let data = collection["123567890"].content;

let data2 = collection[0].content; //I know that's for arrays, but I thought it would be similar
```

Both output 'null' or undefined, with the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
```

So I understand that I cannot get the initial collection object.

One last thing: That number **1234567890** is randomly generated each time the function is called, so I cannot hardcode anything easily.

[Pastebin to the actual collection example.](https://pastebin.com/raw/3mFHpYsA)
For some reason, it stops printing after that line (possibly too many characters?)

EDIT: My code:

```
msg.channel.awaitMessages(msg => msg.author==user, { time: 10000, max: 1, errors: ['time'] })
.then((collected) => {
    let channel = collected[0];
    console.log(collected);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(collected));
    if(channel=="cancel") {
        msg.channel.send("cancel");
        return;
    }
})
.catch(() => {
    // ect ect
});
```

Sorry that there isn't much clarification, this is really stumping me.

Comment: 1234567890 is a function. try `collection['1234567890']().content`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.
`TypeError: collected[msg.id] is not a function` - Please tell me how you got to the conclusion that it may be a function? It may help me.

Comment: show us the exact object. (`JSON.stringify`) . the one shared above doesn't look valid syntax

Comment: The actual one is very long, I'll pastebin it.

Comment: When I use `JSON.stringify(collected)` it returns `{}` - Is there something wrong in the function?

Comment: The returned doesn't seem like a Java script object. can you also share the function that returns this data.

Comment: Alrighty, I'm using Discord.JS and a function named `awaitMessages(filter, options)` - this returns a bunch of data related to what it receives. I can't seem to find the actual function inside of the node module, and there isn't much documentation on it. The best I could find was [the official docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AwaitMessagesOptions) and [whatever this is](https://gist.github.com/oorooroot/091e392cdc45a995b2fade876980c0cd).